# How to deploy selenium project in .NET core to a windows Server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, deployment, windows-server-2012

I have a Selenium Project to test the overall UI performance of another project, it's all working fine locally. The issue now is the deployment. Since the testers who will use it would not be running it on visual studio IDE.

Your help and direction will be deeply appreciated.

I have tried searching for solutions online, but i didn't come across any tangible information that will help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose for .NET core? You can package a .NET console app to a .exe file with a main method and let the testers run the .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by **creating a .exe file from a .NET console app**:

1. Create a *console app* project
2. Write your script in `program.cs` so that the project has an entry point
3. Select *Build Solution* option and go to the output folder which normally is in `C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\[repo name]\bin\Debug\net7.0\files...`
4. .zip the entire folder and share it with the testers
5. Unzip all files onto the Windows Server 2012 and run the *[projectname].exe*

Example of my `program.cs` Selenium script:"

```
using (driver = new EdgeDriver(Options))
{
    try
    {
        selenium = new(driver);
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting script {measurement.ScriptName}");
        Transaction1("T01_OpenMysolution", send, blob);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Something went wrong in the script: " + e.Message);
    }
};
```

I'm just using **Top-level statements** in my entry point class: [Top-level statements - programs without Main methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)